# Login to website that has token programmatically

Tags: android, web

I'm currently building a news application. This news application of mine requires to login into this news website which has a token.

The website: http://www.malaysiakini.com/

So the question here is, is there anyway for me to bypass/retrieve the token ?

Note: 
1. I'm using webview in my application to display the news website. 
2. If possible I want to try avoiding using webview due to it being slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access others internal api's we need to get token. for that we need to login into there account first.
you need other party web interface to `SingleSignOn`. and then keep the token.

without token if third party is not exposing any api then it is not possible.
it depends on how third party want to allow enduser. they may allow some public api without tokens.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading question. I actually meant to place 'retrieve' but I accidentally left it out. So is there any clue for me to retrieve the token?